# Spring/Hibernates concurrent insert issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This issue is happening when two or more Spring Data JPA transactions add the same new entity into Postgres DB concurrently.

I have a service that saves/gets list of Appliances by IDs.

```
    @Transactional
    public List<ApplianceRecord> updateAppliances(List<String> applianceIds) {
        List<ApplianceRecord> existingAppliances = repository.findWithIds(applianceIds);
        List<ApplianceRecord> appliances = service.getAppliances(existingAppliances, applianceIds);
        repository.saveAll(appliances);
        return appliances;
    }
```

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    List<ApplianceRecord> findWithIds(Collection<String> applianceIds);
```

If this method is called concurrently for Appliances those missing in DB, it fails sometimes with following error.

```
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "appliance_session_id_uq"
```

It means different transactions concurrently try to add the same missing entity in db and fails.
When first transaction adds missing Appliance into db the second transaction is not aware of it. The second transaction in call `repository.saveAll()` runs `insert` query instead of `update`.

Using

- Spring Boot 3.X
- PostgreSQL

Comment: Looks like you are gonna need a mutex to obtain access. Once a transaction obtains access, if no element exists, then you insert. Otherwise, you update or do nothing, depending on what you need to do. What is though your expected result? Updating the row with the values of the second transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optimistic Locking in order to prevent concurrent updates to the same entities.
To implement this, you have to alter your existing table and add a new column named 'version'. To demonstrate I assume your ApplianceRecord entity has id and name attributes. Then you need to add version attribute and also @Version annotation should be included as below.

ApplianceRecord.java

```
public class ApplianceRecord {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 @Version
 private Integer version;

 //getters and setters
}
```

Entity manager will take care of the rest process.
You don't need to update the version field.

What is happening behind the scene?

Each time you modify a record in the table, version field automatically increased by 1.

`List<ApplianceRecord> existingAppliances = repository.findWithIds(applianceIds);`

At this line you retrieve all ApplianceRecord entities for given Id list.
Each of these entity has a version. When you try to save again those entities in the table, entity manager looks for the version of the each entity and the existing record in the table. If there is a mismatch between the version numbers it throws OptmisticLockingException.

How you manage the exception?

You can use `@Retryable` annotation to retry if optimistic locking happens.

```
@Transactional
@Retryable(include = {OptimisticLockException.class)
    public List<ApplianceRecord> updateAppliances(List<String> applianceIds) {
        List<ApplianceRecord> existingAppliances = repository.findWithIds(applianceIds);
        List<ApplianceRecord> appliances = service.getAppliances(existingAppliances, applianceIds);
        repository.saveAll(appliances);
        return appliances;
    }
```

Whenever `OptimisticLockException` throws system re-executes the method, default retry attempts is 3. You can configure this.